# Python - creating a struct with '.' from an array of strings

Tags: python, string, struct

I am new to python and wondering if how I can create data struct using '.'
For example, given an array of strings,

```
mystr=['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
commonstr = 'zzz'

for str in mystr
    # something like creating '.' struct
    self = __create_dot_struct_with_value__(self, str, str+commonstr)
```

So the result will look like

```
self.aaa = 'aaazzz'
self.bbb = 'bbbzzz'
self.ccc = 'ccczzz'
```

How can I do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: You cannot. Python does not have C++ structs. :) It has only classes.

Comment: I was looking at some functions like __setattr__ or __setitem__ in dict. Don't these may helpful?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Just pointing out that Python has no structs, only classes. You can do what you ask for with no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
class x(object):
    pass

for item in mystr:
    setattr(x, item, item + commonstr)
```

Now you can do things like `x.aaa`, and have it return `aaazzz`.

`setattr` lets you add object attributes dynamically. I would be very wary of using it inside an existing class unless you're absolutely sure it won't mess up the rest of your class, but if you just want a dummy class, this is a good way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what i wanted.!

Comment: You might like to look at introspection: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pyint/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import namedtuple
my_class = namedtuple("a_class"," ".join(mystr))
print my_class._make([x+"zzz" for x in mystr])
```

might be something that works for your use case

a `namedtuple` is probably the closest thing python has to a `struct` (in the C/C++ sense)

Comment: Thank you for another way to do that!